# Powershell Variable in Double Double Quotes

Tags: powershell, escaping

I have a PS Script that should generate a html file with add-content $datei
works fine but here is the Problem,
I have something like that:

```
"some html...
<textarea id="Text$counter" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></textarea>
some html...
<span>$NameEdit</span>
some html...
document.getElementById('Text$counter').select();
some html...
" | add-content $datei
```

so i have multible double and single qoutes and multible variables in the html part but i cant find out how to escape all that stuff right that the script runs as expected AND fill in the variables in the html code

im using PS 7.0

Comment: You should look at here-strings and the -f (format) operator.

Comment: I read this and some other sites but there is never an example for the problem i have :/ 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you probably want is a **Here String**
But you could also use the escape char **`**

```
@"
some html...
<textarea id="Text$counter" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></textarea>
some html...
<span>$NameEdit</span>
some html...
document.getElementById('Text$counter').select();
some html...
"@ | add-content $datei
```

To use a **Here string** you need to have the `@"` or `@'` then a new line where you will put your string. Then to close a **Here string** you will need to have a new line and `"@` or `'@`. The `"@` or `'@` must be at the very first start of the new line.

Here are some examples that would fail

```
#This will NOT work
@"
Hey There "Buddy"
  "@

#This will NOT work
@"Hey There "Buddy""@

#This will NOT work
@"
Hey There "Buddy""@
```

Here are couple Working correctly examples

```
#This WILL work
@"
Hey There "Buddy"
"@

#This WILL work
  @"
Hey There "Buddy"
"@

#This WILL work
$Test = @"
Hey There "Buddy"
"@
```

It does make beautifying code harder
Example

```
Function Test(){
    $Text1 = "Hello There"
    $Text2 = @"
"Buddy"
"@
    return "$Text1 $Text2"
}
```

Now lets go over the escape char **`**
Its called a **Backtick**.

```
"Hey There `"Buddy`""
```

Is equal to **Hey There "Buddy"**